# Hiding button in JQuery using .prop(hidden: true)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, button

I am trying to figure out how to hide a button with JQuery using the .prop(hidden: true) method. For some reason, in Chrome when I set this value and view the html, the button has a hidden element, but the button still shows up as visible on the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm trying to do this programatically - so I can pass a value as true or false, and hide the button (rather than use the .hide/show methods.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A button does'nt have a hidden property ?

```
$('button').hide();
```

or

```
$('button').toggle(true);  //shows button
$('button').toggle(false); //hides button
```

Comment: Yes - but please see my comment on the original post. I need to do this programatically.

Comment: @2scottish - Okay, changed my answer, is that closer to what you're looking for ?

Comment: Thank you. I had not thought to use toggle for a button. To get this to work correctly within my context, I had to negate the true/false value passed to the toggle function: $('button').toggle(not(var)) - where var is passed to the function from elsewhere.

Comment: I had need a code to just use that true false property for less coding for hiding some divs :)) Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use set the `display` style to `none`. For example,

```
$("#button").css("display", "none");
```

Or, `.hide()` for brevity,

```
$("#button").hide()
```

There's also `visibility` and `opacity` but these two may not generate the effect you desired.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the .css("display", "none") method does work, and I can replace "none" with a variable and pass a value to it programatically. I would prefer to pass simply a true/false value instead of a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can't hide a button using jQuery's `.prop()` function, you have to use either `.hide() or  .fadeOut()` or you can try with `.css()` method:

using `.css()`:

```
$('input[submit]').css('display','none');
```

using `fadeOut()`:

```
$('input[submit]').fadeOut();
```

using `.hide()`:

```
$('input[submit]').hide();
```

Comment: Yes - the .css('display', 'none') option is do-able in my case, but I prefer to pass in a true/false value, rather than use something like 'none'. That's why I selected the toggle answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect, but there's no "hidden" property anyway.  You probably want:

```
$('#your_button').hide();
```

or possibly

```
$('#your_button').addClass('hidden');
```

if you've got a "hidden" class in your CSS.

The incorrect part of your syntax is that the parameters to your function call are expressed incorrectly.  Setting a property should look like:

```
$("#your_button").prop("name", "value");
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.prop is [intended for HTML attributes only](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), things defined on the DOM node. CSS styles aren't applicable things to set with prop, and `hidden` just doesn't exist, whereas `href` or `class` is applicable. Instead you must use `$(el).css('display', 'none')` or `$(el).hide()`.

Comment: Umm "hidden" is not a real CSS property. There's `display: none` and `visbility: hidden` however.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, distracted by lunch. Doesn't change the point about an HTML/DOM attribute being set by `prop()` though.

Comment: Yes indeed, you're right about that of course.  I figured you'd fix it :-)

Comment: Thank you. This helps me understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1):

What you described is actually correct if you happen to use jquery alongside bootstrap4.

just do the following:

`$element.prop('hidden', true);`

If no bootstrap 4 available it is still works for modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

prop() is a getter function: http://api.jquery.com/prop/ I suggest using hide: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Wrong. `.prop()` is a getter and setter function :)

Comment: @Alexander true. I am definitely falling asleep :|

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use prop, then

```
$("#my_button").prop("style").display="none"
```

I would go w/o jquery. (back to the basic)

```
document.getElementById("mybutton").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: A workable solution, but I prefer to use something to which I can pass a true/false value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ternary` operator and the `css()` method to accomplish the same thing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

```
$("#button").css("display", (mycondition) ? "block" : "none");
```