# jQuery - How to hide/show an input box when an option is selected?

Tags: jquery

I want to show an input box when option 1 is selected and remove when option 2 is selected.

```
<select id="a">
    <option id="1">1</option>
    <option id="2">2</option>
</select>


<input type="text" id="cb" style='display:none'>
```

Here's what I've tried.

```
 $('#a').on('change', function() {
    $('#cb').prop('show', id == '1');
 }
```

I want it to be done specifically using `prop` as I've solved my similar problems using `prop` and I want to maintain the uniformity

Comment: The question is unclear. user1162512 says "But I want it to be done using prop", but what is done using prop in the code above doesn't make sense. Are there several input boxes that aren't shown in the code?

Comment: Using the wrong thing to do a job is not maintaining uniformity, it's maintaining bad practice.

Comment: Why using `prop` is considered BAD?

Comment: Using prop to hide/show an element is very bad. You would need to use `.prop('style', 'display:block');` to show, which would remove any other styles, unless you find out what they are first and append to that string, which... get this... is what `.show()` does!

Comment: you can not use prop in this case, showing/hiding an element is mainly depends upon its styling property called `display:none/block`.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy you CAN use .prop(). It's just a bad idea to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

HTML:

```
   <select id="a">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
```

I have changed the `ids` into `values`. Actually its a good practice.

JS:

```
 $('#a').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val()== '1')
       { 
          $('#cb').show();
       }
    else
       {
          $('#cb').hide();
       }
  }
```

Or

`Show` is not a property, actually you can use `.toggle` to achieve it in the same way that you are expecting.

```
$('#a').on('change', function() {
       $('#cb').toggle($(this).val() == '1');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6vEb6/1/)

Comment: He is not using `value` so you will need `.text()`

Comment: @Mr.Alien I have just changed the markup accordingly, inorder to suggest a better way

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy you should explain it than :) I was writing the same answer but you posted so I removed mine....

Comment: @user1162512 can you update your question to show that you want to use prop? It's not the correct thing to do though.

Comment: Please answer my doubt. I want it to be donw using `prop` as I;ve solved one of my similar problem using prop and I want to maintain the uniformity

Comment: @NigelAngel - I apologize. I'll do the needful.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - `toggle` doesnt works. I've tried it.

Comment: +1 This is the correct method. Though it's worth pointing out to OP that IDs of elements must start with a letter. EDIT: I see you've replaced them with `value=` which is not required if the value matches the text of the option element.

Comment: @user1162512 I have provided a DEMO for you, Just have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make this with .prop because this function get|set properties of HTML element. Show and hide for element set in CSS style and not exists property 'show'

Similar question: [Hiding button in JQuery using .prop(hidden: true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900138/hiding-button-in-jquery-using-prophidden-true)

Comment: This is not true. You can do this with .prop(), you just wouldn't.